# ADB via Wi-Fi desconecta quando ligo acessório USB

Tags: android

Estou a utilizar o ADB através de Wi-Fi para poder trabalhar com acessórios USB (Android Open Accessory). Para alguns testes é necessário desligar e voltar a ligar o cabo USB ao telemóvel. Sempre que ligo o acessório USB ao telemóvel, o ADB desliga-se e tenho de voltar a ligar o ADB; isto apesar de estar conectado ao ADB através de Wi-Fi e não cabo.

O comando utilizado é `$ adb connect 194.2.2.51:5555; adb -s 194.2.2.51:5555 logcat -v threadtime MinhaApp:V *:S`.

Como fazer com que o ADB, ligado via Wi-Fi, não se desligue ao conectar/desconectar acessórios USB?

Comment: Porque é que a pergunta não se encaixa no tema do site se Android+AOA é desenvolvimento de software?

Comment: Concordo com você, acho que a pergunta pode sim fazer parte do escopo. Votei para reabrir, assim pelo menos pode ser que alguém deixe uma opinião do por quê ela não deve ser reaberta, que no momento não consigo ver.

Comment: @Daniel Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Creio que a pergunta foi fechada porque alguns usuários confundiram sua pergunta com um pedido de suporte técnico do tipo "meu aparelho está com defeito".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

isso acontece por que quando você conectar o cabo USB, o device ira detectar novamente o USB e ativalo como porta de entrada do adb automaticamente. para isso nao acontecer você precisa forçar o device a utilizar TCP/IP, mas para isso o device precisar ter acesso root. Você pode criar seu proprio script ou pode utilizar algum [app já pronto para isso.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.wifiadb&hl=pt_BR)

[how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp)

Espero ter ajudado